# catch exception on jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using Jenkins pipeline to orchestrate some binaries. My Jenkins slave host has "open-ssh" with full access to the servers in the dev environment.
Is there a way to catch ssh exception using Jenkins pipeline? Here is my code:

```
//exe remote command on server
stages {
    stage('Links') {
        steps {
            sh '''#!/bin/bash
                ssh user1@server1 command1
                ssh user2@server2 command2
                '''
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work for you:

```
stages {
    stage('Links') {
        steps {
           script {
              try {
                 sh "ssh user1@server1 command1"
              } 
              catch (err) {
                // do something about it, or simply
                throw err
              }

              try {
                 sh "ssh user2@server2 command2"
              } 
              catch (err) {
                // do something about it, or simply
                throw err
              }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im using this to wrap my pipeline jobs:

```
#!groovy
node ('node1') {
    currentBuild.result = "SUCCESS"
    try {
        stage('stg-1') {
            ...
        }
        stage('stg-2') {
            ...
        }
    } catch (err) {
        print('err: ' + err.toString() )
        currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
    } finally {
        stage('stg-final') {
            ...  
        }
    }
}
```